# Which is the best way to Lazy load using Intersection observer API or CSS content-visibilty rule?

Tags: performance, core-web-vitals

We are trying to optimize LCP of our site by implementing "Infinite scroll" on our web pages either using Lazy load using Intersection observer API or CSS content-visibilty rule.
I need to know which one is more effective?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat dependent on your site in question. I would immediately say that just setting `content-visibility: auto` to sections below the fold is a [known pattern for improving rendering performance](https://web.dev/content-visibility/#skipping-rendering-work-with-content-visibility) (just be sure to use `contain-intrinsic-size` as well to avoid layout shifts. Letting the browser to as much as possible with just HTML and CSS will typically result in better performance (provided all is done correctly).

However, the better puzzle may be looking into what is causing the LCP measurements to be slow. If there are multiple images on the page, changing the [`fetchpriority`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchpriority) of images can tell the browser to load the main image first. Looking at script order and making sure all code is deferred when possible is another easy win for LCP. Most of the time, there are other opportunities to more significantly change the LCP measurement (unless the DOM is truly massive, e.g. [David Bowie's news page](https://www.davidbowie.com/news)).